# How do I create a parent- child navigation with site pages? SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, pages

I'm using SharePoint 2010.
How do I create a parent-child navigation on a flat site collection with only pages witch lays in the pages library?

I what it to bee shown only when a user clicks on the first link.

Right now all the pages is in the library "Pages" and I whant to show them like this:

+pages

```
+page 1
    page 2
+ page 3
   + page 4
   + page 5
```

And so on, I also what that only the part that is active should bee open like:

+pages

```
+pages 1
+pages 3
   + pages 4
   + pages 5
```

Do you know How i can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it using browser, just use "Edit Links". Check this for more information,

[MSDN blog - Custom Navigation in SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/modonovan/archive/2008/05/30/custom-navigation-in-sharepoint-the-full-monty.aspx)

If you want to do it by code as you want "+" sign I guess, so this is the best approach to your probelm,

[MSDN blog - How to create custom navigation menu in SharePoint with XML data source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matjazperpar/archive/2008/12/17/how-to-create-custom-navigation-menu-in-sharepoint-with-xml-data-source.aspx)

Or

http://sharepoint2010customnavigation.blogspot.co.uk/